# Fermat Primality Test Haskell

Tags: haskell, math, primality-test

I have implemented the following two functions for establishing if n is a fermat prime number (will return n if its true, -1 if not), but it returns always -1, can't figure out why (gc is a funct taht calculates gcd)

```
fermatPT :: Int -> Int
fermatPT n = fermatPT' n list
  where
    list = [a | a <- [1..n-1]]

-- | heper function
fermatPT' :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
fermatPT' n l      | gc (n, head l) == 1 && fermatTest n (head l) = fermatPT' n (tail l)
                   | null l                                       = n
                   | otherwise                                    = -1
                where
                  fermatTest n a = mod (a^(n-1)) n == 1
```

Comment: Why not `True` or `False`? I do not really get why you encoding things as `Int`s, if these are truth values

Comment: Or if you need to return the number, Just n and Nothing

Comment: `list` is somewhat pointless; you can just write `fermatPT n = fermatPT' n [1..n-1]`.

Comment: If it always return -1, then there is probably something wrong with `gc` that causes it to never return 1.

Answer (score 2):

Your function should return a boolean indicating if the given number is a prime. If you do that, you can use the `all` function to define this simply as

```
fermatPT :: Integer -> Bool
fermatPT n = all (fermatTest n) (filter (\a -> gcd n a == 1) [1..n-1])
             where fermatTest n a = mod (a^(n-1)) n == 1
```

`gcd` is defined in the Prelude.

`all` avoids the explicit recursion that requires you to apply the test to one element of `[1..n-1]` at a time; its definition is effectively

```
all _ [] = True
all p (x:xs) = p x && all p xs
```

---

Note that `mod (a ^ (n - 1)) n` is inefficient, since it may require computing an absurdly large number before ultimately reducing it to the range `[0..n-1]`. Instead, take advantage of the fact that `ab mod n == (a mod n * b mod n) mod n`, and reduce the value after each multiplication. One way to implement this (not the fastest, but it's simple):

```
modN :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
modN a 0 _ = 1
modN a b n = ((a `mod` n) * (modN a (b - 1) n)) `mod` n
```

Then use

```
fermatTest n a = modN a (n-1) n == 1
```

Note that you could use this (with `Int` instead of `Integer`) to correctly implement `fermatPT :: Int -> Bool`; although the input would still be restricted to smaller integers, it won't suffer from overflow.

Comment: I know it should return a bool, but the second part of the exercise is to return the lower fermat witness if n is not prime.

Comment: And still this solution doesn't work unfortunately, fermatPT 53 return false, should return True

Comment: You are running into overflow errors with the naive computation of `a^(n-1) mod n`; changing the type signature to `Integer -> Bool` seems to fix it. (For example, `52 ^ 52 :: Int == 0`, while `52 ^ 52 :: Integer == 170676555274132171974277914691501574771358362295975962674353045737940041855191232907575296`).